# recursively traversing an XML Element using DocumentTraversal in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have been using the following code structure to traverse XML documents and it works pretty well:

```
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.*;
...

private static SomeReturnType traverse(Document doc) {
    DocumentTraversal dt = (DocumentTraversal) doc; // line-a
    NodeIterator i = dt.createNodeIterator(doc, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, false);
    Node node = i.nextNode();
    while (node != null) {
        // do stuff   
        node = i.nextNode();
    }
    return ...
}
```

However, how is it possible to generalize the above to allow traversal in a random XML Element of the document, and not just the document as a whole? This should theoretically be easy as in XML the document could be seen simply as the outermost element, yet the API is counter-intuitive.

In other words how would you write the above function to take an `Element` or a `Node` as an argument?

**UPDATE**

Solution seems to be:

```
private static SomeReturnType traverse(Node rootNode) {
    DocumentTraversal dt = (DocumentTraversal) rootNode.getOwnerDocument();
    NodeIterator i = dt.createNodeIterator(rootNode, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, false);
    Node node = i.nextNode();
    while (node != null) {
        // do stuff   
        node = i.nextNode();
    }
    return ...
}
```

Comment: First thing, isn't is a risky assumption that the passed `Document` implements `DocumentTraversal`? The javadoc states `In DOMs which support the Traversal feature, DocumentTraversal will be implemented by the same objects that implement the Document interface.` so I don't think you could always make this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your method take a `Node` instead of a `Document`. Notice that `DocumentTraversal` takes `Node`.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have implemented an `Iterator` / `Iterable` wrapper around `NodeList`. It simply uses `NodeList.getLength()` to determine the number of elements. So what I would do is pass a `Node` to the method and use `Node.getChildNodes()`. You can either use the `NodeList` directly or wrap it in an `Iterator`.

Comment: In that approach you wouldn't get the attributes which are not children of any node whereas the document traversal can be generalized with a SHOW_ALL filter to return attributes as well. Or am I missing something? Anyway I now have an implementation thanks to your previous answer which you deleted so I can't accept.

Comment: I undeleted it just in case it is right but seems like a bad assumption to cast a `Node` to a `DocumentTraversal`.